# Align text in nav html tag

Tags: html, css

I want to align my title horizontally center in my `nav` tag. The nav consists of a button to expand a vertical side bar and the title. I'm using the `text-align: center;` tag but it is not working.

**Here is my navbar along with the title

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: brown;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.title {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <span class="open-slide">
    <a href="#" onclick="openNavbar()">
      <svg width="30" height="30">
        <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" />
        <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" />
        <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" />
      </svg>
    </a>
  </span>
  <div class="title">Random Title</div>
</nav>
```

Kindly help me center `Random Title` in the center of the nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nav button is taking up room, resulting in a not quite centered title. Use `position: absolute` to make it not take up any room. Note that it will cover up your title on smaller screens so you'll need to either decrease the font size or make multiple lines.

To make sure the button is positioned correctly make the parent (`.navbar`) `position: relative` and then add `top: 0px` and `left: 0px` to the button to put it in the top left corner.

```css
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: brown;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.title {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <span class="open-slide">
    <a href="#" onclick="openNavbar()">
      <svg width="30" height="30">
        <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" />
        <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" />
        <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" />
      </svg>
    </a>
  </span>
  <div class="title">Random Title</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: That didn't center the title. It just messed the nav button position, but the title still isn't centerd

Comment: @Mark, Oh. What code are you adding to this? Based on your reply it sounds like your navbar has more than 2 children (button and text). Fixing the position of the navbar button can easily be fixed. Check my edit

Comment: The nav bar only has two children while the button opens a side bar which I think is not causing the problem here

Comment: The title is still isn't centered. I can manage the button position but I'm struggling with title alignment

Comment: @Mark, Ok. Is the snippet centered for you? If it is, make sure your code isn't adding any horizontal padding or margins to the text, even if it's even to both sides.

Comment: @Jack I think what he wants is to center the title but take count the hamburger menu that is actually taking space of the bar. So the bar minus the hamburger menu.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem was with with bootstrap. navbar was interfering with navbar bootstrap class. anyway thanks for your time

Comment: @Mark, sure. Gald you got it sorted out

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.  calculate the amount of margin-left you need to position the element in the center

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: brown;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  
  
}

.title {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  margin-left:calc(50% - 164px/2 - 62px);
  
  font-size: 30px;
  display:inline-block;
  
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <span class="open-slide">
    <a href="#" onclick="openNavbar()">
      <svg width="30" height="30">
        <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" />
        <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" />
        <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="5" />
      </svg>
    </a>
  </span>
  <div class="title">Random Title</div>
</nav>
```